# how to detect the button event by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to detect the button event in the page,I inject my **script.js** strong text file from **background.html**, when button is click,I want to alert some message than let button do his work.
so I have two question,

1.I try to use **jquery** in my **srcript.js** but its seem not work,i have include jquery file in     **background.html**, how can i use jquery in .js file?

2.how to detect button event when it be click?

below is my code:

**background.html**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:'script.js',allFrames:true});
  });
</script>
```

**script.js**

```
if( self.frameElement && self.frameElement.tagName == "IFRAME" ){
  $(":button").bind("click",function(){
    alert("iframe button");
  });
}
else{
  $(":button").bind("click",function(){
    alert("parent button");
  });
}
```

Comment: `$(":button")` looks wrong. Should be something like `$("button.myClassName")` or `$("#myButtonId")`.

Comment: thanks Beetroot, i'm try this two method, but still not work, is there other wrong in my code?

Comment: I have to admit, I have no experience of writing chrome extensions. You did modify my suggestions with a real classname / real id didn't you?

Comment: Yes I did. I use my classname and my id, but it's does not work. I had try juzerali's method, and it's work!! Thanks Beetroot-Beetroot to help !! I appreciate it!!

Comment: juzerali's answer shows he clearly has the right knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As to why jQuery in your script is not working, that is because you have included jQuery in your `background page`, you need to load it into the user's page's extension's world. To make it clear. Your `script.js` is supposed to be loaded in user's page. Chrome will load into the page but in an `isolated world` which is your extension's world on that page. You have to load jQuery on that page just like your `script.js`. As below:

```
<script>
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:'jQuery.js',allFrames:true});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:'script.js',allFrames:true});
    });
</script>
```

As to your other question regarding listening to button clicks, its unclear from your question which button are you speaking of. Is it the browser action button? If that is the case your code will work just fine. If it is a button on user's DOM, you will have to add script as described above that listens to the click event and informs your extension (`background.html`), your `background` page in turn will load the script.

Comment: Thanks juzerali for help! I inject jQuery.js than it's work now!! The second question is that i want to listen to button on user's DOM,when i use the method that you seggest than my code can alert some message,so thanks very much!!

Comment: +1 Very interesting. I didn't know any of this was available in Chrome.

Comment: @JuzerAli What if there is a button on a html page being created via a background.js file?

Comment: @Volatil3 Do you mean the web page or the `popup` page.